# Four weeks in Italy, France, Switzerland, Ireland — 3 UK SIM best?

Tags: europe, cellphones

I am interpreting Three UK's [About Feel At Home](http://support.three.co.uk/SRVS/CGI-BIN/WEBISAPI.DLL?Command=New,Kb=Mobile,Ts=Mobile,T=Article,varset_cat=roaming,varset_subcat=4157,Case=Ext(EM38751)) and [Pay As You Go](http://www.three.co.uk/Store/SIM/Pay_As_You_Go) pages as:

I buy a 20 GBP Three SIM from eBay UK and then, in September, I can use 12GB in the four countries listed (the only restriction I found relevant is about two full months of usage, I will toss the card before the first is out).

I have an LTE tablet, I only need data (and perhaps receive SMS). Is this the correct interpretation? Because if it is, then this is a crazy deal. Is there some catch I missed?

Comment: Be very careful about what you are buying. What you need is a 3 UK SIM that is activated (i.e. already has a number) with £20 of credit in the account. Just before you travel you'll use the £20 to buy the add-on. If the SIM card you get is unactivated (as is normal) you'll need to make sure it can be activated outside the UK, and I think you'll need a separate £20 top-up voucher since buying credit on-line requires a UK bank card. I use this, and it works, but I was in the UK when I got the SIM and have a UK card to top up with from overseas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there is no catch. I am a three customer myself who benefits regularly from this perk.

However I do believe you need to be a three customer for 1 full month before you can start benefiting from the 'Feel at Home' offer although I cannot find any sources regarding this so it may have expired. They do also say that it is designed for UK residents but I am not sure if they check this through (not sure if you are a resident or not) and it is not compatible with the 'Essentials plan'

The only thing I would be wary of is buying a SIM card from eBay. What benefit would you get over buying from three directly?

The link you posted has all the available information about the offer.

Comment: Well, since I am not in the UK I do not know how would I buy anything from Three UK if not eBay.

Answer (score 2):

Flyertalk points out these two articles https://jmcomms.com/2015/11/02/sort-it-out-three-using-data-abroad-feels-nothing-like-at-home/ https://jmcomms.com/2015/11/05/three-admits-it-slows-data-for-roamers-so-where-do-we-go-from-here/ which points out Three UK throttling *very* heavily when abroad:

> On a short trip to Germany last week, I forgot to install the British Airways app to check in for my flight home. The app isn’t massive (it’s around 24MB), but it took the best part of 10 minutes to download.

Three sort of acknowledges:

> We have put a number of steps in place to ensure the majority of customers are able to fully enjoy the most popular services when on holiday abroad on their handset like Facebook, Instagram, Google Maps and web browsing. Hopefully that clears things up.

So that 12GB? That's sort of pointless. I will try to put on pretty [red socks](http://darkk.net.ru/redsocks/) and see whether they throttle that and report back in September.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a roaming data service without any explicit speed constraints a good value is a [Google Project Fi](https://support.google.com/fi/answer/6157794?hl=en) SIM, which charges a flat US$10/GB for data everywhere it works, on LTE/4G where available. The drawback is you need someone in the US willing to acquire it for you, but if you have that the roaming data service is quite good.

I use Three in Europe because its service includes voice minutes and I use them. For data Project Fi is better.